# Featured Image not Showing Up on WhatsApp

Tags: wordpress

When I paste post URL in Whats app chat it is only fetching the Title but not the featured image or any image. On other social media platforms like Facebook, Twitter there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the source code I've noticed you have the og:image meta declared 3 times:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
```

Its declared twice like above with blank content so I suspect this is why nothing is showing, it looks like one is within your theme and another is within the "Open Graph Meta Data by WP-Open-Graph plugin"

Comment: So what is next, uninstall WP-Open-Graph plugin is needed

Answer (score -1):

This problem is mostly caused by SEO plugins. Simply change the SEO plugin you are currently using. I will recommend you change your SEO Plugin to one that works fine with your theme.

Comment: Please share more details such that others can learn from your answer. What **exactly** would you recommend?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).